# removeConstraint() not removing constraint

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a weird problem. I want to change a constraint in certain conditions, but `removeConstraint` doesn't work. The constraint doesn't get removed.

Here's the code:

```
backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.removeConstraint(constLabelTop)
let constNew = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: backButton, attribute: .CenterY,multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(constNew)
```

The constraint `constLabelTop` is a constraint which sets the top of the `label` a few points above the `backButton`. Why doesn't it work?

The new constraint clashes with the old one and the `backButton` gets squashed.

I tried `backButton.removeConstraint` too and didn't work either.

Comment: call layoutIfNeeded after adding final constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
constLabelTop.active = false
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: backButton, attribute: .CenterY,multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: no need to change `addConstraint` and `removeConstraint` into `active = false` or `active = true`, the result is the same and the intent is clear.

Comment: I can't use `.active`. The app is compatible with iOS 7 too. But I did the necessary changes and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent to each other. You can use one of them.